# VueJS: how to get route url?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am working in laravel with Vue, and I can't get route url.
For example there is route localhost:8000/chat/3 and I need to get 3 in route
I tried in app.js to write in

```
data: {
    userId: this.$route.params
}
```

and then in

```
created() {
    console.log(this.userId);
}
```

So i can send ajax request to that route. But it returns `TypeError: this.$route is undefined`. I tried also with other things than `params` but it allways show this error

Comment: Can you try the same but making `userId` a computed property instead? I think that, when Vue binds the datas, the other properties are not ready yet.

Comment: I tried, made a function getUserId and in it `return this.$route.params`. Got the same error. Maybe I am missing something, since I am begginer in Vue - do I need vue router for this?

Comment: Or can I somehow send user id directly to app.js (not components)

Comment: If you're willing to use routes then yes you absolutely need `vue-router`